# How to show daily at intervals of 15 days?

Tags: c#

I should show dates spaced every 15 days.

example:

```
01/01/2013 - 15/01/2013

31/01/2013 - 15/02/2013
```

In particular I should display the last month with the same method, but considering always the lapse of 15 days, i.e. if today is October 18, I will have to see:

```
15/09/2013 - 30/09/2013

01/10/2013 - 15/10/2013
```

How do I proceed?

Comment: Your examples are inconsistent. You have a span of 15 days, 16 days, 16 days and 15 days again.

Comment: Yes, I have to take a month and consider a cadence of 15 days.

January is 31 days I will have:

01/01/2013 - 15/01/2013

16/01/2013 - 31/01/2013

September is 30 days, then:

01/09/2013 - 15/09/2013

16/09/2013 - 30/09/2013

So sometimes it will be 15, sometimes 16, depends on the number of days in a month.

Answer (score 2):

With `DateTime` object, you have a method called `AddDays()`

Just use it like this :

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dtIn2Weeks = dt.AddDays(15);
```